# Can I use a foreign travel card to make an online transaction from India to a website hosted in the US?

Tags: credit-card, foreign-exchange, legal

I have a foreign travel card valid for paying in the US from Thomas Cook. I'm an Indian citizen and currently in India. I want to make an online payment via a website hosted in the US. Is this possible?

The card allows me to make online payments to local websites (like amazon.com) when in the US. So I think it should work even if I physically am in India, but is this indeed the case? Note that transactions in India are not allowed via these forex cards.

Comment: You can always try.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know for a specific card without trying it, but in general, the only way the issuing bank would know where you are physically located would be if the merchant passed your IP address in (which is possible, but very rare unless coupled with something like MasterCard's [SecureCode](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/features-benefits/securecode.html)) or if you used an Indian billing address. Barring those, the bank would just know where the merchant is located.

This all assumes the *merchant* lets you make purchases while out of the country, though. I've been blocked from making purchases based on not being in the correct country once or twice.  That isn't impacted by what card you have, though.